# How to "reactivate" system shortcuts after instaling other Desktop Envirernments

Tags: 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, desktop-environments

I have installed a few other desktop environments on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine, and after doing so, I discovered that <kbd>Super</kbd> doesn't work anymore! It doesn't pull up the menu on any DE. I also found out that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> doesn't work anymore either. How would I go about fixing this? In settings, these shortcuts are not displayed, so I have no clue how to. Thanks!

Edit: I have installed the following DE's:
Budgie Desktop
Cairo-Dock (GNOME)
GNOME 3
GNOME Classic
Kodi
Pantheon
Plasma
Ubuntu (Unity)
Unity8-Mir
Xfce Session
Xubuntu Session
awesome

The keyboard shortcuts were working after I installed GNOME 3, GNOME Classic, Unity8-Mir, and Budgie Desktop. <kbd>Super</kbd> and other system shortcut keys worked with all of them (might it have something to do with Compiz?). After installing the other DE's, it was then that I noticed the keys weren't working. It's only some combinations that do work, I primarily use GNOME 3, and I found out that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> opened the activities view. But in Unity, I found out that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> wasn't working. I am very confused, I think that some system shortcuts work, and some do not. I also noticed that the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key isn't working. Even playing a flash game in Firefox, <kbd>Esc</kbd> is just not read!

I would like to get these keyboard shortcuts back for any DE that uses gnome shell. So Unity, Gnome 3, Gnome Classic, Budgie Desktop, and Cairo-Dock. I don't care about Unity8-Mir, though.

Comment: On which DE does super bring menu?

Comment: None, it's like the key on the keyboard is dead, but tried 3 other keyboards and still doesn't work.

Comment: As far as i know, Unity uses Super key to bring dash, Cinnamon uses it for menu. other than this two, KDE, XFCE, LXDE doesn't use super key at all. Which DE you installed and on which DE you wanted to bring menu with Super Key?

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Please add, on which DE you're expecting `super` to work? on which DE `Alt-Tab` doesn't work ? was it working before installation? on which DE settings you looked and didn't find shortcuts?

Comment: I have edited the question again with more info.